# VS Code emmet custom snippets in .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, emmet

I'm loving the power of Emmet snippets in VS Code as I am new to this IDE. I have a question that I can't seem to google to get an answer. So I figured out how to add emmet snippets into my .vue files by adding the following into my VS code settings.json:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "vue-html":"html",
    "vue":"html",
}
```

And that works well, but I wanted to add a couple custom snippets, so I added this entry as well:

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": [
    "C:\\CodeSnippets"
],
```

The relevant code in one of those snippet files is the following:
{

```
"html": {
  "snippets": {
    "ull": "ul>li[id=${1} class=${2}]*2{ Will work with html, pug, haml and slim }",
    "oll": "<ol><li id=${1} class=${2}> Will only work in html </ol>",
    "vgc": "{ Wrap plain text in curly braces }",
    "ig": "{import ${1} from './${2:components}/${1}.vue'}"
  }
},
"css": {
  "snippets": {

  }
}
```

}

Now when I'm inside of a '.html' file I can type `oll` and it will add the snippet as seen in screenshot .
[image]

But when inside of the .vue file I type the same thing and nothing happens. Now I know Emmet is working in my .vue file because I can do other emmet stuff in there as seen in screen shot below:
[image]

I'm sure I'm missing some type of configuration but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: have you filed an issue at the VSC repo or Emmet extension for VSC

Comment: @rioV8, no I have not. How do I do that?

Comment: Emmet is baked-in into VScode, so a simple [issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) would be enough. Otherwise, go to the documentation page of a plugin and in the same approach, open a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably

`> Snippets: Configure User Snippets`

Then selecting

`vue-html.json`

With this example JSON

```json
{
  "test snippet": {
    "prefix": "vvtest",
    "body": [
      "some ${1:test}"
    ],
    "description": "some random test snippet for the template part of Vue"
  }
}
```

[image]

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> and you'll get the following

[image]

---

PS: note that the `${1:test}` part will make that `test` is highlighted so that it can be quickly overridden. You can also cycle towards a number 2, 3, etc...with other `$2 ...` with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Here is the [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) for this feature.

Comment: the OP wants to have his custom Emmet snippets also in Vue files working

Comment: @rioV8 I'm not sure how to do such a thing, hence why I proposed what I know. In this case, it can pretty much do the same thing if not more.

Comment: @kissu, I'll try this out. In the end I don't care how it gets done as long as it can be done in VSC.

Comment: @Jose that one is probably the fastest/easiest way to achieve a result like that IMO.